# Hide a taskbar item without sending it to tray

Tags: windows-8.1

Is it possible to hide (not send to tray) a taskbar icon? The program is always open in the icon tray (next to the clock, small icon).

Comment: You mean just any program? You could hide the window using a program like [Window Hide Tool](http://www.window-hide.com/).

Comment: I want to keep the window open.

Comment: Do you want the taskbar icon to be always hidden or only on demand?

Comment: @and31415 Always

Comment: Then you might be out luck unless you have full control (i.e. source code available) of the program which creates the icon in first place. In fact, you can't really hide taskbar icons but just [add/delete them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Even if you were to delete the icon, it can reappear again (e.g. when the program's window become active). You could set a timer to keep deleting the icon, but that isn't a perfect solution. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739574/hide-another-apps-taskbar-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control which icons appear in the taskbar notification area (the area next to the clock) in Control Panel-All Control Panel Items-Notification Area Icons.

To make it completely go away, set it to "Hide Icon and Notifications".

Comment: I want to keep those but remove [this](http://puu.sh/6TV8I.jpg)